# Maven site error with version range

Tags: maven

I have a Maven project that declares a dependency on another Maven artifact using an open ended version range, such as this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.terracotta.toolkit</groupId>
  <artifactId>terracotta-toolkit-1.0</artifactId>
  <version>[1.0.0-SNAPSHOT,]</version>
</dependency>
```

(I know that it is to some degree asking for trouble using such version ranges, but for this particular project we have very good reason for doing so.)

For the most part this works fine, but when trying to generate the project web site with "mvn site", I get the following error when it tries to create the Dependency Management Report:

```
[INFO] Generating "Dependency Management" report. Downloading: http:/XXXXXXXXXX/content/groups/public/org/terracotta/toolkit/terracotta-toolkit-1.0/[1.0.0-SNAPSHOT,]/terracotta-toolkit-1.0-[1.0.0-SNAPSHOT,].pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Invalid uri 'http://XXXXXXXXXX/content/groups/public/org/terracotta/toolkit/terracotta-toolkit-1.0/[1.0.0-SNAPSHOT,]/terracotta-toolkit-1.0-[1.0.0-SNAPSHOT,].pom': escaped absolute path not valid
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Trace java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid uri 'http://XXXXXXXXXX/content/groups/public/org/terracotta/toolkit/terracotta-toolkit-1.0/[1.0.0-SNAPSHOT,]/terracotta-toolkit-1.0-[1.0.0-SNAPSHOT,].pom': escaped absolute path not valid
```

As you can see from the message, it tries to construct a URI with the open ended version range specification instead of the resolved version number, which of course fails.

Can anyone tell me if there is a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in Maven 2.2.0 that was fixed in Maven 2.2.1.  I was mistaken that I was using Maven 2.2.1 already.

Comment: Nice, glad you found a problem & a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Does it work properly if you fix the version of the terracotta artifact to 1.0.0?

Also, which version of Maven are you using? As per this link:

- https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html

if you are using Maven 3.x, you will have issues with `mvn site`.

Comment: It does work fine when the artifact is fixed to version 1.0.0 (or any other specific version number).  I am still using Maven version 2.2.1 for the site generation (and have also tried Maven 2.2.0).